# Installing jsftp in ubuntu

Tags: node.js

How to install jsftp in my ubuntu machine?
I wa[image]s tried using command npm install jsftp it is giving error like which i have attached in the screenshot.

Thanks,
Pradeep Raj.K

Answer (score 0):

The package `jsftp` exists on npmjs.org, but you are using a different registry.

See https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-registry.html.

Answer (score 0):

The registry you are trying to use does not seem to exist, or is malformed.  You can check the registry you are using via `npm config get registry` or `npm config list`

```
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

You can set it to the above (which should be working) with `npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"`

You can also do `npm install --registry=<valid-registry>` if you don't want to change your configuration.